# How to correctly instantiate Classes, Variables and Objects for best performance?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-optimization

I'm creating a GUI in C# and I'm trying to increase the starting/loading performance, because I have to load a lot of stuff in other classes.

I've read something about late and early binding, but I think both ways are early binding in .NET.

I have a basic question and I try to figure out what's the best way to instantiate classes / variables: directly at the beginning or in the constructor? Or does it make no matter for the Compiler ?

I have 2 options, which is the better (faster) option?

**Option 1:**

```
public partial class MainClass : Window
{

    private SomeClass someClass1;
    private OneMoreClass someClass2;
    //....
    private String someString;
    private int someInt;


    public MainClass()
    {
        this.someClass1 = new SomeClass();
        this.someClass2 = new OneMoreClass();
        this.someString = "test 12345";
        this.someInt = 42;
    }

    // ....
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
public partial class MainClass : Window
{

    private SomeClass someClass1 = new SomeClass();
    private OneMoreClass someClass2 = new OneMoreClass();
    //....
    private String someString = "test 12345";
    private int someInt = 42;


    public MainClass()
    {
        // nothing to construct
    }

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a superb post entitled [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). I'd suggest you should read it.

Comment: Why don't you try to measure which one is the fastest? And this way, you will be able to see the amount of time you will gain.

Comment: I can't measure the time at the very first beginning. It's no problem to measure the time for some loops, but idk how to measure before instantiating any classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try yourself by test ;-)
But on site [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io) you can see IL code for c# code.

And for program:

```
using System;
public class C {
    private A A = new A();
    public C()
    {
    }

    public void M() {

    }
}

public class A
{
}
```

IL code is:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private class A A

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 18 (0x12)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: newobj instance void A::.ctor()
        IL_0006: stfld class A C::A
        IL_000b: ldarg.0
        IL_000c: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0011: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2063
        // Code size 1 (0x1)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ret
    } // end of method C::M

} // end of class C

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit A
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2065
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method A::.ctor

} // end of class A
```

And for:

```
using System;
public class C {
    private A A;
    public C()
    {
        A = new A();
    }

    public void M() {

    }
}

public class A
{
}
```

IL code is:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private class A A

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 18 (0x12)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: newobj instance void A::.ctor()
        IL_000c: stfld class A C::A
        IL_0011: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2063
        // Code size 1 (0x1)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ret
    } // end of method C::M

} // end of class C

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit A
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2065
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method A::.ctor

} // end of class A
```

The differnce is in constructor, some methods but in different order. So should be same fast.

```
 instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 18 (0x12)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: newobj instance void A::.ctor()
        IL_000c: stfld class A C::A
        IL_0011: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 18 (0x12)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: newobj instance void A::.ctor()
        IL_0006: stfld class A C::A
        IL_000b: ldarg.0
        IL_000c: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0011: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor
```

Comment: @Toberto If I have helped, please vote for my answer and if I have solved the problem, please indicate it as an answer.

Comment: I already voted, but I need 15 reputations :( ... I marked it as an Answer